# Encoding Cyrillic to UTF-8 in my sidebar.php file the site breaks

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am just writing to you after 4 hours of searching through my Wordpress theme's files, and I finally found the reason why my sidebar goes to the far left.

It seems that when my sidebar.php file is encoded in UTF-8, and is with cyrilic text, it will get deplaced for some reason. But when with that same text, it is encoded in ANSI, the text comes out garbled, but the sidebar remains on its position.

Can you please help me make the final push towards the solution to how to have both readable cyrilic text and the sidebar on its rightful place.

Thanks a lot!

If you want ot check out the code of the sidebar with the cyrilic on, here is a pastebin link.

http://pastebin.com/1LEgrKDa

Comment: Maybe that will help you http://www.art-coder.com/2010/06/20/little-bit-about-encoding/

Comment: Eugene, thanks a lot for your input. I'll try to execute mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8"); like it said in that article, though I don't think this is a db issue. I compared a working sidebar.php file with the non working one using a Notepad++ Plugin, and the only difference it showed was the language. A important thing to know is, that when I set it up to ANSI, the cyrilic isn't readable but the sidebar stays in place.

Comment: Also your files must be in `UTF-8 without BOM` and you should have on your webpage `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

Comment: Eugene, if I could, I would shake your hand and give you a bro fist. It worked perfectly, you're awesome. Have a great day, and here is an internet hi-five from me.... Slap!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That article "[Little bit about encoding](http://www.art-coder.com/2010/06/20/little-bit-about-encoding/)" should help you with your problem.